# Is it correct to use a comma in the following case?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> The detectives couldn't help each other. Perhaps this "madness"—despite coming from the same source,
>   investigating crime scenes—was different for each of them.

I'm not sure whether the comma between the em dashes is correct. Is the comma the right choice for this example?

Comment: Despite coming from the same source — investigating crime scenes — this "madness" was perhaps different for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"despite coming from the same source, investigating crime scenes" is a parenthetical statement. Within that, "investigating crime scenes" is another parenthetical statement. Using different delimiters for each statement (em dashes for the first level, and a comma for the second) is appropriate.

It could be punctuated differently, e.g.:

> The detectives couldn't help each other. Perhaps this
>   "madness" (despite coming from the same source - investigating crime
>   scenes) was different for each of them.

Comment: Yes. I prefer your commaless version. Commas are overworked, and the function of the comma here is a little hard to pick up – perhaps especially as it appears at the end of a line here. I might be tempted to swap your brackets and dash. Merely style.